# How can I use RMSE as my scoring metric for my Time Series Split grid search?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am doing a time series split for my training and testing sets for a Random Forest Regression, and have a grid search that finds the optimal number of splits based on the MSE:

```
ms_error = make_scorer(mean_squared_error)
def n_splits_checker(model, split):
    scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=split, scoring=ms_error)
    print("Split: {} \n".format(split))
    print("Loss: {0:.3f} (+/- {1:.3f}) \n".format(scores.mean(), scores.std()))
```

This code works perfectly fine, but when I try to change the scoring to RMSE using this code:

```
ms_error = make_scorer(mean_squared_error(squared=False)
```

I get this error:

```
mean_squared_error() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y_true' and 'y_pred'
```

In the original code I do not have to pass these arguments. How can I change my code to use RMSE as the scorer?

Answer (score 0):

There is [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) for that:

```py
from functools import partial

root_mean_squared_error = partial(mean_squared_error, squared=False)
rms_error = make_scorer(root_mean_squared_error)
```

Essentially, `partial` returns a function such that when it is called, the arguments you supplied are passed to it (the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) explains it very well).